Help deciding how to run electric for new outlet off of existing circuit
I have 3 outlets on an existing circuit and would like to add one more.

Outlet 1 is in the garage and loads outlets 2 and 3. New outlet could be straight down from this on the reverse side of the wall.
Outlet 2 is an exterior outlet. New outlet could also be right next to this on the reverse side of the wall.
Outlet 3 is also in the garage, but far away from where I want the new outlet.

If I use outlet 1, I could run a new length of Romex straight down through the wall along the stud. But there are already 2 load lines coming off this outlet, and would need to pigtail a third in an already pretty full box.
If I use outlet 2, it would be right next to the other outlet and there is enough slack that I could cut the existing Romex and "patch" in the new outlet.
Neither one seems obviously better or worse to me, so just wondering what others preferences would be (or none of the above if I am way off base). Thanks!

You are required to have six inches of the outer cable covering stripped of(six inches of single wires in the box).  Would be surprised if you have that much slack, very lucky if you do.  Garage/outdoor outlets are required to be GFCI protected now.  Unknown if adding a new outlet to the circuit would cancel grandfather option, if not GFCI protected now.

Is your new outlet going to be inside or outside?

It sounds like the receptacle you want to add is not in the garage or outdoor. The NEC requires a garage circuit that feeds only garage (and outdoor by exception). See text:   https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/2/wiring-and-protection#210.11_(C)_(4)  . I referenced Colorado because the have adopted the code with modification.

@NoSparksPlease well darn, you are correct. Thank you for that.

@Machavity inside

@Jordan inside the garage?

Based on the description, I believe you have:

Panel -> Outlet 1
Outlet 1 -> Outlet 2
Outlet 1 -> Outlet 3
New location (outlet 4) is near outlet 2

Assuming all that is true, do not cut the cable/wires going to outlet 2 (that just won't work because you won't have enough extra wire to do it properly). Instead, add a new cable from the additional screws on outlet 2 to outlet 4. Any standard receptacle has two sets of screws and when there are no special situations (e.g., half-switched or MWBC) you can use the second set of screws to daisy-chain to another location.
If these receptacles are already GFCI-protected (outlet 1 is GFCI/receptacle or breaker is GFCI/breaker) then you don't have to worry about GFCI protection. If not, now is the time to resolve that. Depending on the box size of outlet 1, you may be able to replace the existing regular receptacle with a GFCI/receptacle, or you may need a bigger box to do that.

The new location can be near outlet 1 or outlet 2. But that is correct. I have a pre-drywall picture and it looks like I would have about 2 feet of slack near outlet 2, so it might be tight, but I think it could be done. With outlet 2 being an exterior outlet, I was hoping to avoid running anything else back inside through that box.

Do a box fill calculation on outlet one to see if you can add the pigtails. If you have two load wires off it, you're probably using the backstabs which is a bad idea or you double hooked the screws which is bad.
Hard to believe that outlet 2 has enough slack to allow 6" of cable in and out but if it does, go for it but remove backstabs at outlet one if they exist.
Garage outlets need GFCI protection

Outlet 1 is GFCI. And when I pulled it, yes they had both loads in the backstabs. So I thought I would pull the backstabs, pigtail those with the new load wire, and then run a single load from the pigtail to the screw. That would leave me with 4 wires in a single pig tail which just felt like a lot. As far as outlet 2, I have a pre-drywall picture and I would estimate I have about 2 feet or so to work with in there.
